# laravel unit testing with factories Unable to locate factory with name [default]

Tags: laravel, model, phpunit, factory

I try to create a factory for one of my models in laravel unit test

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use phpDocumentor\Reflection\Types\Parent_;
use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Auth;
use App\Role;
use App\AppName\HolidaysEmployees;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class TestApiCalls extends TestCase
{


    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->user = factory(User::class)->create([
            'firstname' => 'RA',
            'lastname' => 'Tester',
            'password' => bcrypt('tester'),
            'email' => 'ra@tester.com'
        ]);

        $this->holidays = factory(HolidaysEmployees::class)->make();
    }

}
```

but when I run the test I keep getting

```
InvalidArgumentException: Unable to locate factory with name [default] [App\MyName\HolidaysEmployees].
```

What I do wrong in this case?

Comment: Well do you have a factory for `HolidaysEmployees::class`?

Comment: oops, thanks for feedback I forgot about

Answer (score 0):

I found how to fix this online:

Change

```
class TestApiCalls extends TestCase
```

to

```
class TestApiCalls extends \Tests\TestCase
```